# Complex Numbers - Weird Equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm not sure if it is a error typing in the book or just something I can't solve hope you could help me, so here it is:

$$z \bar z+z^2 = \bar {\bar z} - z +2$$

This is the same way they write it in the book,

Thanks :)

Comment: is not $\bar {\bar z} = z?$

Comment: @abel yeah it is

Comment: @JMoravitz no, there is no conditions

Comment: Oh, you are looking for what $z$ works, not trying to prove that for all $z$ the equation holds... I see now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $z=a+bi$ where $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

Now noting that $\bar{\bar z}=z$,
$$z\bar z+z^2=\bar{\bar z}-z+2$$
$$\iff z(\bar z+z)=2$$
$$\iff (a+bi)\cdot 2a=2$$
$$\iff 2a^2=2\quad\text{and}\quad 2ab=0$$
$$\iff a=\pm 1,b=0$$

Answer (score 6):

Since $z\overline{z}$ and $2$ are both real, the only way the equation can have solutions is if $z^2$ is real: that is, if $z$ is either purely real or purely imaginary. If $z$ is purely imaginary, then $z^2=-z\overline{z}$, so their sum cannot be $2$. If $z$ is purely real, then $z^2=z\overline{z}$. So the equation reduces to $z^2=1$, meaning that $z=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Let me try. Putting $z =a + bi$.

we have: $$(a+bi)(a-bi) + (a+bi)^2 = 2 \\ a^2+b^2 + a^2 -b^2 + 2abi  = 2\\ 2a^2 + 2abi = 2.$$

Then $2a^2 = 2$ and $2ab=0$.

So, $a = \pm 1$, $b =0$.